# Is it possible to perform active rendering in Java Swing without being on the EDT?

Tags: java, swing, animation, event-dispatch-thread

I am looking into using [Buffer Strategy](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and the following technique described on the Javadoc:

```
// Main loop
while (!done) {
 // Prepare for rendering the next frame
 // ...

 // Render single frame
 do {
     // The following loop ensures that the contents of the drawing buffer
     // are consistent in case the underlying surface was recreated
     do {
         // Get a new graphics context every time through the loop
         // to make sure the strategy is validated
         Graphics graphics = strategy.getDrawGraphics();

         // Render to graphics
         // ...

         // Dispose the graphics
         graphics.dispose();

         // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer contents 
         // were restored
     } while (strategy.contentsRestored());

     // Display the buffer
     strategy.show();

     // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer was lost
 } while (strategy.contentsLost());
```

}

It would be great to avoid [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread) and `invokeLater` or `invokeAndWait` when performing an animation.

My questions:

- If this is in a Swing application don't we need to worry about putting the call to `show` on the EDT?
- Can anyone else see any problems using this in a Swing app?

This was inspired by this [interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963494/java-2d-game-graphics/1963684#1963684) to game programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, no. Painting on a thread other than the [event dispatch thread (EDT)](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html) results in undesirable artifacts, although the results may be acceptable. This [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/threadwatch) demonstrates some of the trade-offs. I prefer arranging to draw on the EDT using [javax.swing.Timer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html), but [other approaches](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/) are possible. Also, your chosen top-level [Container](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) may already implement a [Buffer Strategy](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by trashdog it is not good idea to do so. Create own animation thread which will draw off-screen image. Then push it to some holder. If paintComponent is called fetch current image and draw it on component. Done. Look at rendezvous pattern.